# Binding json to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I am looking for a library that gives me a lightweight method of binding json to existing dom elements rendered by a rails view template.

The reason I need to do this is that my app allows in place editing (using best_in_place) and as a result of those edits other data on my pages needs to be updated and displayed back to the user in real time. Within an edit success callback, I am making an ajax call to my API to grab a json object containing the recalculated values I want to display. Just need to bind that result to existing DOM elements.

I am we'll aware of libraries like angular.js and knockout.js, and while I have not ruled them out, I am hoping to identify a lighter option. Maybe a jquery plugin.

I did find [jquery-load-json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/), but it is not quite what I'm looking for. It wants to render the HTML for me based on a template. I just need the dynamic binding of json to existing Dom elements.

I'd welcome any thoughts, and am open to other ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)

D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG and CSS. D3’s emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern browsers without tying yourself to a proprietary framework, combining powerful visualization components and a data-driven approach to DOM manipulation.

View example in http://jsfiddle.net/jmeza/G52cC

Html Code and Script d3.sj

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <table class="letters">
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
// create some people
var people = [{
    upper: 'A'
}, {
    upper: 'B'
}, {
    upper: 'C'
}, {
    upper: 'D'
}];

var table = d3.select('table.letters');
var rows = table.selectAll('tr').data(people);

console.log('rows', rows);
```

if you look chrome console can see that the json data attribute is bound to the DOM element:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. I've looked at the jsfiddle you provided, but it doesn't appear to be binding to the javascript object you instantiated.